# R: How can I use apply on rows of a data.frame and get out $column_name?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to access $a using the following example:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("x","x","y","y"),b=c(1,2,3,4))

> df
  a b
1 x 1
2 x 2
3 y 3
4 y 4

test_fun <- function (data.frame_in) {
    print (data.frame_in[1])
    }
```

I can now access $a if I use an index for the first column:

> apply(df, 1, test_fun)

```
  a 
"x" 
  a 
"x" 
  a 
"y" 
  a 
"y" 
[1] "x" "x" "y" "y"
```

But I cannot access column $a with the $ notation:  error: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

```
test_fun_2 <- function (data.frame_in) {
    print (data.frame_in$a)
    }

>apply(df, 1, test_fun_2)
Error in data.frame_in$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use `adply` from the plyr package instead:

```
library(plyr)
adply(df, 1, function (data.frame_in) print(data.frame_in$a))
```

Comment: Beautiful. I spent quite a while looking for questions on "how do I use apply on dataframe" coming with workarounds which in the end could only solve the specific problem at hand. This one not only answer all the questions I saw but solved mine as well!

Answer (score 11):

because `data.frame.in` is not a data.frame:

```
apply(df, 1, function(v){print(class(v))})
```

but you can access the named elements with:

```
test_fun_2 <- function (data.frame_in) {
+     print (data.frame_in['a'])}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `apply` changes the data type in your function:

```
> apply(df, 1, class)
[1] "character" "character" "character" "character"

> apply(df, 1, colnames)
NULL
```

Since there are no column names, you can't reference the values with the `$` operator.

From the `apply` documentation:

> If X is not an array but has a
>   dimension attribute, apply attempts to
>   coerce it to an array via as.matrix if
>   it is two-dimensional (e.g., data
>   frames) or via as.array.

Comment: No suggestion as to how to mitigate this problem?